How do I fix the border color in windows 10?
I changed my accent color two years ago and now all of my internet browsers (explore, chrome, and firefox) borders are stuck with this color.  I have installed a new theme, changed themes, changed accent colors, and many more settings.  App and other programs do not have this issue.  Any help would be appreciated.
Last year, I had an issue with my user profile being corrupted and I changed a setting in reg edit, but ended up having to factory restore to fix the user profile.  Not sure if this would also be an issue, just wanted to point this out.
Screen grab of firefox next to settings window.

Please don't edit the answer into your question. [su] is a question and answer site and answers should be separate from questions. Please read Can I answer my own question?
